# Youtrack REST: setting default value for project custom field

Tags: rest, youtrack

I am implementing a release mechanism for my application and want to couple it with my YouTrack using the REST API.

Upon the release I want to set the default value of 
*'Fix Version'* for newly created issues to the *bumped version*.

The *Fix Version* is a project's custom filed. When I query for it via REST API i get

```
<projectCustomField name="Fix version" type="version[1]" emptyText="Unknown" canBeEmpty="true">
    <param name="bundle" value="MyProject Versions"/>
    <defaultValue>2.8</defaultValue>
</projectCustomField>
```

The [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/POST+Project+Custom+Field) mentions just the way to change the *name* and an *unset value text*. I have tried POSTing the *dafaultValue* and *dafault* parameters, but with no effect. Is it's possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

I have contacted JetBrains, and apparently this functionality is, sadly, not there.